# Using navigation graph with viewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-viewpager

I've started using the navigation graph an it's great, but I am facing a certain confusion.

My app has a camera feature. After the user takes a photo, "Fragment A" opens to display the image on 2/3 of the screen, where at the bottom of the screen there is a view pager hosting two fragments, let's call them "Fragment 1" and "Fragment 2", and they are taking the user through a couple of steps to add information about the image.

After completing the steps, in Fragment 2, the user has an upload button that would perform the upload and then needs to take the user to a completely different fragment, "Fragment B". This fragment is at the same level as Fragment A and has nothing to do with the viewPager (it's the image feed).

My question is, in the navigation graph, when I create actions, should this final action be from fragment 2 to fragment B, or from fragment A to fragment B?

*Also, I'm new here so not sure if it's alright or not but I have another question regarding the same situation.

When clicking submit/upload, how can fragment 2 get from fragment A the image's URI?